# perl find a pattern between two patterns inside bash

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sh

I am looking for a regular expression using perl in a bash file (*.sh).
I need to find  a dynamic pattern between two pattern.

For example:

```
some data 
.
.
.
Pattern1
.. data
Dynamic_Pattern
...data
Pattern2
.
.
data
.
.
Pattern1
..data
Pattern2
```

the output will be:

```
Pattern1
.. data
dynamic pattern
...data
Pattern2
```

I found this code on the web:

```
perl -n0e 'while (/Pattern1.*?((?=Pattern2)|(?=$))/sg) {$x=$&;print $x if $x=~/$Dynamic_Pattern/}' file
```

the problem is that it does not work if the Dynamic_Pattern id dynamic, only if it static

Comment: `$Dynamic_Pattern` comes from the calling bash-script?

Comment: yes the perl scrip is in side a bash function that init the Dynamic_Pattern                                                                                   `perl -n0e 'while (/Pattern1.*?((?=Pattern2)|(?=$))/sg) {$x=$&;print $x if $x=~/$Dynamic_Pattern/}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass the "dynamic" part as argument to the perl-oneliner. Otherwise perl treats it as "his" variable, which is undefined of course. You can enable basic commandline-arguments  with the `-s`-switch (look [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)). The `\Q` before the pattern should ensure that potentially problematic characters are quoted.

```
perl -sn0e 'while (/Pattern1.*?((?=Pattern2)|(?=$))/sg) {$x=$&;print $x if $x=~/\Q$dynpattern/}' -- -dynpattern="$Dynamic_Pattern" file
```

Comment: I'd double quote $Dynamic_Pattern.

Comment: yeah, was just thinking about putting a `\Q` in front.

Comment: fixed the order of switches and added the `--` before the arg, not it seems to work as expected

Comment: `perl -n0es 'while (/Pattern1.*?((?=Pattern1)|(?=$))/sg){$x=$&;print $x if $x =~/\Q$dynamicKey/}' -dynamicKey=$enteredKey test.txt` i keep getting Substitution pattern not terminated at -e line 1.

Comment: Yeah thats why i changed the order to `perl -sn0e`.. Take the cmd from above please.

Comment: Wow thanks I missed the -- near the end it is working now, I was stuck for hours!!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to pass two arguments to the [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) script. The first one the dynamic pattern to search, and the second one the file with the content. The script will use flip-flop to extract the range of lines between both edge patterns.

Assing the value:

```
searched_pattern="Dynamic_Pattern"
```

And run the `perl` script:

```
perl -ne '
    BEGIN { $pat = shift }
    if ( my $range = ( m/\A(?i)pattern1\b/ ... m/\A(?i)pattern2\b/ ) ) {
        $data .= $_;
        if ( ( q|E0| eq substr $range, -2 ) && ( $data =~ m/^\Q${pat}\E\b/m ) ) {
            printf qq|%s|, $data;
        }
        else {
            next;
        }
    }

    if ( $data ) { undef $data }
' "$searched_pattern" infile
```

It yields:

```
Pattern1
.. data
Dynamic_Pattern
...data
Pattern2
```